# How to prevent react-router from refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**What's the problem?**

I am building a project in reactJs with react-router-dom v5. I have added a default route to routing

> <Redirect to={"someComponent"}/>

Now the problem is that a simple refresh also redirects me to the default route. How to prevent that?

Code snippet:
App.js

```
return (
      <div className="App">
            <Switch>
               <div id="wrapper" className="main_page">
                 <ErrorBoundary resetState={state}>
                  <Header/>
                    </ErrorBoundary>
                      <div id="page-wrapper" className="mainContentArea">
                        <Route path={`/dashboard/units`} component={Dashboard} />
                          <ErrorBoundary resetState={state}>
                            <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading..</div>}>
                              <Route path={`/dashboard/someRoute`} component={someComponent} />
                            </Suspense>
                          </ErrorBoundary>
                        <Redirect to={"someComponent"}/>
                
                     </div>
                </div>
           </Switch>
      </div>
    );
```

Can someone help me with the above problem? Due to Redirect in App.js, I am redirected to dashboard even with a simple refresh

Edit:I have Router and BrowserRouter in a separate component.This is just a snippet

Comment: I cannot see `<Router>` in your code. Is it missing or did you just wrap it somewhere outside this code?

Comment: Can you give an example of your issue? Are you getting redirected to `SomeComponent` when you are at `/dashboard/units` and hit refresh in browser?

Comment: yes. If I am at /dashboard/units and I hit refresh, It redirects me to someComponent(which is my dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `exact` prop to `<Redirect to="/dashboard/units" />` but before that don't forget to wrap your routes into BrowserRouter: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter